# Not understanding The Reasoned Schemer Chapter 5 frame 62

Tags: logic-programming, minikanren, reasoned-schemer

I am currently learning miniKanren by learning The Reasoned Schemer.

And I am stuck in an exercise in Chapter 5 frame 62: `(run* (x) (flatten_o (a) x))`, why there are three lists in output?

Comment: Please provide some more context: a link to the exercise for instance

Comment: I don't know if the e-book is available online, but I know the code is here: https://github.com/miniKanren/TheReasonedSchemer

Answer (score 4):

Good question!  Where do these extra lists come from???

The problem is in the `else` clause of the definition of `flatteno`.  The `else` clause handles the case in which `s` is a symbol (the symbol `a`, here).  However, the clause also allows `s` to be the empty list or a pair!  This is why we see three lists instead of one---the extra two lists are produced by recursive calls that succeed due to the `else` clause accepting non-symbol values for `s`.

In later versions of miniKanren we have added special constraints such as `symbolo` and `=/=` to prevent such behavior.  For example, here is the same query, and `flatteno`, written in faster-miniKanren (https://github.com/webyrd/faster-miniKanren):

```
(define flatteno
  (lambda (s out)
    (conde
      ((== '() s) (== '() out))
      ((fresh (a d res-a res-d)
         (== (cons a d) s)
         (flatteno a res-a)
         (flatteno d res-d)
         (appendo res-a res-d out)))
      ((symbolo s) (== (cons s '()) out)))))

(run* (x)
  (flatteno '(a) x))
=>
((a))
```

Note the use of the `symbolo` constraint in `flatteno` to ensure `s` is a symbol.

You can find a non-"Little Book" explanation of these constraints in this paper:

http://webyrd.net/quines/quines.pdf

We are trying to figure out how to include a description of these constraints in a Little Book format.  The implementation of the constraints is a bit involved, which makes it hard to fit in a Little Book!

Hope this helps!

Cheers,

--Will